# Creating buttons one by one from selected rows in tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UItextfield which works like a search bar. I clicked on UItextfield to search it shows the suggestion in UItableview, then if I clicked on a particular row I want it to create a button in some other view I have created and tableview hides, then again searches for other person again a button will be created in that view.

Like this:

[image: this is how I want]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with?  Communication between views, or creating the buttons?

Comment: creating button one by one as user press on the row of tableview.